# How to run storyboard on textblock string is changed in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am wondering if any simple technique to run storyboard if textblock text string was changed. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is xaml for a user control that will animate the opacity of an item when the Text property of a TextBlock is changed.

It is using a PropertyChangedTrigger and ControlStoryboard action to cause this to happen.  These items come from dlls that get installed with Blend, but you can install them separately if you don't have Blend: [Blend 4 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=d197f51a-de07-4edf-9cba-1f1b4a22110d)

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    x:Class="TextboxAnimation.MainPage"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="AnAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                Storyboard.TargetName="animationTextBlock">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Click Me To Change Text"
            MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlockClicked">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBlock}">
                    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource AnAnimation}"/>
                </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="animationTextBlock"
            Text="Animate Me!" Margin="0,8,0,0" Opacity="0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Here is the code behind that is used for the click event, which changes the TextBlock Text property:

```
int times = 0;

private void TextBlockClicked(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    times++;

    textBlock.Text = String.Format("I've been clicked and changed {0} times!", times);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. It is great. However, I will not click on the textblock. I will update the text dynamically. I just need to run the animation when it will happen. It will be much easier in WPF but I need it is Silverlight. Any ideas?

Comment: In this example, the animation will run anytime "textBlock.Text" is changed.  I'm just changing it when the click occurs for the sake of demonstration, but it can be changed from anywhere.

Comment: I have the newest SDK. I cannot locate Interactions/Interactivity behaviors. Should I install older SDK? Thank you.

Comment: I finally was able to add Interaction and Interactivity dlls. Now, it is working great. Thank you for the info! I highly appreciate it.

Comment: What if I want some sort of If Else Condition here and Switch Storyboard according to a certain value.

Comment: If you want to jump into code behind, you can subscribe to the textBlock.PropertyChanged event, and handle any change you want with any storyboard you want.

Comment: @SudheerKovalam Additionally, you can use a ConditionBehavior (Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.ConditionBehavior) in your xaml so that the trigger will only be executed in certain conditions.  I would use this in simple cases and if you're able to use Blend to help set it up.  Code behind in general is going to be more flexible.